# Print PDF scaled-down and aligned

Tags: printing, pdf, cups

I want to print a PDF file with all pages scaled down equally (to, say, 70 %). The scaled-down pages should then be left-aligned on the printing paper.

This doesn't seem to be possible with `lpr` alone. With `pdfjam` I can scale the pages (`--scale 0.7`) but I don't know/see any option to align the scaled pages. A negative offset (like `--offset '-3cm 0cm'`) doesn't work.

Comment: Negative `pdfjam` offset works for me. There may be something special about your PDF file or you did something wrong.

Comment: very strange, --offset "-5cm 0cm" does *nothing*, -9.5m 0cm does nothing either, but -10cm 0cm —— BANG 10 cm offset. what the hell? also: the content is then off-page. I think I need to change the paper size or something like that?

Comment: What page size is the file? Providing a example file may also help.

Comment: The original page size is A4 (din a4) and I also want to print it on A4. So for testing purposes any A4 pdf file will work, really. Or actually any standard-sized pdf, given I want to print pdf with $pagesize out with $pagesize, just transformed like described: scaled down, and aligned to the left.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, got it. The key to success is to explicitly specify paper size.

For example, if the original PDF has DIN A4 page size, then

```
pdfjam --a4paper --scale 0.5 --offset "-7cm 0cm" -- inputfiles
```

does the trick. I'm not sure why -x with x<10 didn't work before.

Comment: I believe the offsets not working might have been due to automatic margin-trimming being enabled in my PDF reader (e.g. in Okular View->Trim View->[x] Trim Margins).

Comment: Where did you find documentation on this? I can't find this answer by searching for scaling pdf on linux command line.