# Print a PDF with scaled content

Tags: pdf

I have a 150 page long pdf file where individual pages are shrunk. I need to magnify the file upto 900% to read anything on the screen (and it is readable at that magnification). I would like to print it out but the printer only gives me the original unreadable output.

I am trying to copy the original pdf into a file with correct magnification. I have tried pdfjam as used here ([Print PDF scaled-down and aligned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146852/print-pdf-scaled-down-and-aligned))  and fiddled with pdftk -resize version without any success. Any Help will be appreciated.

I am using  a Linux Ubuntu distribution.

Thank you in advance!!!!!

My Latex Version is : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013)

My Linux version is: Linux 3.13.0-44-generic #73-Ubuntu SMP Tue Dec 16 00:22:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Here is a link to the logfile at pastebin: 
http://pastebin.com/UhY3hDpT

Comment: Can you detail what you tried with `pdfjam` and `pdftk` *exactly*?

Answer (score 2):

I can do it with `pdfjam` with a little trick. Suppose the starting PDF is `test.pdf`; I run:

```
pdfjam --no-tidy --scale 1.0 --trim "7cm 7cm 7cm 7cm" -- test.pdf
```

and the output file is the original PDF, cropped by 7cm from left, bottom, right and top, giving the following `test-pdfjam.pdf` results:

[image: example of pdfjam output]

Using `--scale 9.0` gives a out-of-bound error (you can see it with the `--no-tidy` option), because it tries to use a really huge page. Printing it with a "scale to full page" option should solve the problem (if you need to print it, I mean).

I am using `pdfjam` version `2013.20140215-2` on a Linux Ubuntu 14.04, which sports TeXlive 2013 (`2013.20140215-1` to be exact).

Comment: Thanks @Rmano for the help. When I am tried your solution (and various combinations e.g. scale to full page, different trim options etc) I am consistently getting an error : Calling PDFLATEX Failed. I can generate the log file which seems to say I am over Tex memory (I can put it up here).

Comment: You can add the excerpt of the log where it is failing to the question --- or a link to paste.bin. Add also which Unix flavor you have and which version of the LaTeX suite.